# Gulp-watch is not picking up new files

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm trying to run a task whenever a file get's changed, delete or a new file is added. The first two work, however: when a new file is added it's not being picked up.

I installed the package `gulp-watch` and I have this task:

```
var gulp  = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  watch(
    ['./src/Scripts/**/*.js'],
    function(ev, cb) {
      console.log('test');
      cb();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/shama/gaze/pull/103

Comment: @Heikki The folder is not empty. It contains files that are being watched already.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That was a weird problem. Removing `./` from glob fixes it.

```
var gulp  = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch(['src/Scripts/**/*.js'], function(event, cb) {
        console.log('test');
        cb();
    });
});
```

Comment: Lol, it's still an issue too.

Comment: Still a problem with gulp cli 3.9.1, thank you for the answer, saved my day.

Comment: seems like gulp is buggy and not worth attention yet... I have same problem and I'm giving up. I will go with good old grunt.

Comment: holy crap dude! you are awesome... how on earth did you manage to find this out :O